# How to show something is differentiable on a set or an interval?

Tags: real-analysis

I know how to prove something is differentiable at a point, but my book does not exactly prove differentiability on a set. Is there a concise theorem or proof that covers this?

Comment: When you say something, you mean a function?

Comment: See Bartle's *Introduction to Real Analysis* for a $\delta-\epsilon$ criterion.

Comment: What page of Bartle?

Comment: "The basic theory of the derivative is given in the first part of Chapter 6"

Comment: @GNUSupporter, sure but those definitions use differentiability at c, and Im wondering about differentiability on a set.

Comment: @Sean Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is like the derivative, you show that the derivative exists in a generic point and then you can extend the concept. Also for the differentiability, you can do exactly the same.

Note that for a function of one variable the two things coincide thus the function is differentiable exactly in the same intervals or set where derivative exists and vice-versa.